# How to create function that returns nothing

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, void

I want to write a function with `pl/pgsql`. 
I'm using *PostgresEnterprise Manager v3* and using shell to make a function, but in the shell I must define return type. If I don't define the return type, I'm not able to create a function.

How can create a function without return result, i.e a Function that creates a new table?

Comment: [Please check out my answer if using PostgreSQL 11+ for a method of doing this with `PROCEDURE`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70076078/124486)

Answer (score 261, accepted):

Use `RETURNS void` like below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION stamp_user(id int, comment text) RETURNS void AS $$
    #variable_conflict use_variable
    DECLARE
        curtime timestamp := now();
    BEGIN
        UPDATE users SET last_modified = curtime, comment = comment
          WHERE users.id = id;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: For other readers, note that the `#variable_conflict` directive has *nothing* to do with the rest of the answer. It's just part of an example function; the only important bit is the `RETURNS void`. Also, cool, I didn't know PL/PgSQL had pragmas.

Comment: Here's a related case making use of `#variable_conflict`: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105828/3684

Comment: How do I make use of this function inside of another function? If I try without `SELECT * FROM stamp_user(...)`, then I get `error: query has no destination for result data` and if I just write `stamp_user(...)` then I get `syntax error`.

Comment: @pir What you are saying doesn't make total sense. However, If you don't want to do anything with the SELECT data use PERFROM. If you do. you will want to SELECT * INTO _record Where _record is defined with DECLARE _record RECORD; before the BEGIN statement

Comment: Late to the question, but replying to @pir's comment and to future readers for clarity's sake, there was a misunderstanding in the comment's question and response. When invoking your function, If you see the error `query has no destination for result data`, you are most probably using `SELECT` IN YOUR FUNCTION. So replace the `SELECT` with `PERFORM` in your function, and then call your function as per normal using `SELECT yourFunction()`. `PERFORM` is only valid in pl/pgsql context. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22805260/11537143)

Answer (score 13):

## PostgreSQL 11+: `PROCEDURE`s

[PostgreSQL 11 introduces `PROCEDURE`s](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) which are basically functions that return nothing, but called with `CALL` rather than `SELECT`,

> How can create a function without return result, i.e a Function that creates a new table?

Like this,

```
=# CREATE PROCEDURE create_table_foo()
AS $$
  CREATE TABLE foo ( id int )
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

=# CALL create_table_foo();


=# \d foo;
                Table "public.foo"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer |           |          |
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions must always return something, although you can use procedures like

```
do $$
```

and start with normal function like

```
declare
...
```

but if you still want to do a function just add **void** after **returns**.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the [PL/pgSQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) which returns nothing with `VOID` type and with or without `RETURN;` as shown below. *Be careful, if you return a value with e.g. `RETURN 2;` for `VOID` type, then you get [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698503/plpgsql-error-return-cannot-have-a-parameter-in-function-returning-void/77609986#77609986):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN                           -- ↑ Here
RETURN; -- Here
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN                           -- ↑ Here
-- RETURN; -- Here
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In addition, you can create the [SQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) which returns nothing with `VOID` type as shown below. *A SQL function cannot have [RETURN statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS VOID AS $$
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto the accepted answer, if you see the error `query has no destination for result data` when invoking your function, you are most probably using `SELECT` in YOUR FUNCTION in one of your statements. Replace the `SELECT` with `PERFORM`, and then call your function as per normal using `SELECT yourFunction()`.

Note: `PERFORM` is only valid in pl/pgsql context. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22805260/11537143)