# plpgsql Error: RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning void

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql

I am trying to extract the count of records corresponding to a specific date and user_id which do not have corresponding user_id for the next later date in the database. This is the way I am trying to accomplish it (using plpgsql but not defining a function:

```sql
DO
$BODY$
DECLARE
    a date[] := array(select distinct start_of_period from monthly_rankings where balance_type=2);
    res int[] := '{}';
BEGIN
    FOR i IN array_lower(a,1) .. array_upper(a,1)-1
    LOOP
        res := array_append(res,'SELECT COUNT(user_id) from (select user_id from monthly_rankings where start_of_period=a[i] except select user_id from monthly_rankings where start_of_period=a[i+1]) as b');
                i:=i+1;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN res;
$BODY$ language plpgsql
```

I get an error:

> ERROR:  RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning void
> LINE 11:   RETURN res;

I am new to this procedural language and cannot spot why the function is returning void. I do assign the values to variables , and I declared empty - not NULL - arrays. Is there a syntax or a more significant reasoning mistake?

Answer (score 11):

1. You cannot `RETURN` from a [`DO`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14653151/939860) statement **at all**. You would have to [`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) instead. Possibly a temporary function, see:

   - [Is there such thing as a "temp function"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124912/is-there-such-thing-as-a-temp-function/29133390#29133390)
   - [How to create a temporary function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990622/how-to-create-a-temporary-function-in-postgresql)
2. You don't need any of this. Use this query, which will be faster by an order of magnitude:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT start_of_period
        , rank() OVER (ORDER BY start_of_period) AS rn
   FROM   monthly_rankings
   WHERE  balance_type = 2
   )
SELECT c.start_of_period, count(*) AS user_ct
FROM   cte c
JOIN   monthly_rankings m USING (start_of_period)
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM cte c1
   JOIN   monthly_rankings m1 USING (start_of_period)
   WHERE  c1.rn = c.rn + 1
-- AND    m1.balance_type = 2 -- only with matching criteria?
   AND    m1.user_id = m.user_id
   )
-- AND balance_type = 2  -- all user_id from these dates?
GROUP  BY c.start_of_period
ORDER  BY c.start_of_period;
```

This includes the last qualifying `start_of_period`. You may want to exclude it like in your PL/pgSQL code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR: RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning void

Because the types of `RETURNS VOID` and `RETURN 2;` (`INTEGER`) are not the same in a [PL/pgSQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN                           -- ↑ Here
RETURN 2; -- INTEGER
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So, I set `RETURNS INTEGER` as shown below, then the error was solvd:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
BEGIN                             -- ↑ Here
RETURN 2; -- INTEGER
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or, I returned nothing with or without `RETURN;` as shown below, then the error was solvd:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN                           -- ↑ Here
RETURN; -- Nothing
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN                           -- ↑ Here
-- RETURN; -- Nothing
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```