# Is there such thing as a "temp function"?

Tags: postgresql, function

There are temp views and temp tables - are there "temp functions"?  I have a function that I'd like to use during a transaction, and then discard afterwards (similar use case to a temp table.)  Also I'd like two concurrent transactions to be able to create this same function with the same name without lock contention.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990622/how-to-create-temporary-function-in-postgres

Comment: You mean DO ? If so, then yes. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html

Answer (score 6):

There is no `CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ...` like the existing `CREATE TEMP TABLE ...`. But there is the "trick" to create a function in the temporary schema `pg_temp`, like the [linked answer provides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9981540/939860). The function is only visible within the same session and can only be called by schema-qualified name:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pg_temp.f_inc(int)
  RETURNS int AS 'SELECT $1 + 1' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

SELECT pg_temp.f_inc(42);
f_inc
-----
43
```

I could trace back the idea to [this post by Tom Lane on pgsql-general](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/15191.1208975632@sss.pgh.pa.us).

The closest thing without tricks would be a **prepared statement**. Acts much like a *temporary SQL function* that dies at the end of the session. Not the *same* thing, though, only for a single DML statement, and can only be used by itself, not nested in a bigger query. Example:

```
PREPARE upd_tbl AS
UPDATE tbl t SET set_name = $2 WHERE tbl_id = $1;
```

Call:

```
EXECUTE upd_tbl(123, 'foo_name');
```

Details:

- [Split given string and prepare case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018991/split-given-string-and-prepare-case-statement/28220532#28220532)