# PSQL Command Line Arguments in DO script

Tags: postgresql, command-line, parameter-passing, plpgsql, psql

I've got a script `NewSchemaSafe.sql` that creates a new schema based on the project directory; it's called from the Windows command line as follows:

```
for %%a in (.) do set this=%%~na
-- other stuff here
psql -U postgres -d SLSM -e -v v1=%this% -f "NewSchemaSafe.sql"
```

`NewSchemaSafe.sql` is as follows:

```
-- NewSchemaSafe.sql
-- NEW SCHEMA SETUP 
--    - checks if schema exists
--    - if yes, renames existing with current monthyear as suffix
-- NOTE: will always delete any schema with the 'rename' name (save_schema)
--       since any schema thus named must have resulted from this script 
--       on this date - so, y'know, no loss.
SET search_path TO :v1, public; -- kludge coz can't pass :v1 to DO
DO
$$
DECLARE
       this_schema TEXT:= current_schema()::TEXT;
       this_date TEXT:= replace(current_date::TEXT,'-','');
       save_schema TEXT:= this_schema||this_date;
BEGIN
    IF this_schema <> 'public'
    THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Working in schema %', this_schema;
        IF EXISTS(
            SELECT schema_name
              FROM information_schema.schemata
              WHERE schema_name = save_schema)
        THEN
           EXECUTE 'DROP SCHEMA '||save_schema||' CASCADE;';
        END IF;
        IF NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT schema_name
              FROM information_schema.schemata
              WHERE schema_name = this_schema
          )
        THEN
          EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA '||this_schema||';';
        ELSE
          EXECUTE 'ALTER SCHEMA '||this_schema|| ' RENAME TO '|| save_schema ||';';
          EXECUTE 'COMMENT ON SCHEMA '|| save_schema ||' IS ''schema renamed by SLSM creation on '|| this_date ||'''';
          EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA '||this_schema||';';
        END IF;
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'SCHEMA IS % SO PARAMETER WAS NOT PASSED OR DID NOT STICK', this_schema;
    END IF;
END
$$;
```

Now I know that the `SET` happens, because I can see it on the command-line output. However the rest of the script dies (gracefully, as intended) because it seems to think that `current_schema` is `public`: the script yields

```
psql: NewSchemaSafe.sql:39: NOTICE:  SCHEMA IS public SO PARAMETER WAS NOT PASSED OR DID NOT STICK
```

I had initially tried to pass `:v1` to the `DECLARE` block of the `DO` loop as follows:

```
 DECLARE
       this_schema text := :v1 ;
       this_date text := replace(current_date::text,'-','');
       save_schema text := this_schema||this_date;
  [snip]
```

But that just dies on the vine: it throws a syntax error -

```
psql:NewSchemaSafe.sql:40: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 4:        this_schema text := :v1 ;
```

It does not make a difference if the `%this%` is enclosed in quotes or not in the batch file.

So as usual, two questions:

1. How come the `set search path` statement doesn't 'stick', when I can
   **see** it executing? UPDATE: not relevant, pls ignore.
2. How can I pass the `:v1` parameter to the `DO` script itself?

Environment: PostgreSQL 9.3.5 64-bit (Win);

Weirdnesses: I am certain that this script worked two days ago, and  the only change was to remove the byte-order-mark inserted by geany (UTF BOMs make `psql` gag).

**UPDATE**: the reason it worked the other day was that it was being run in a situation where the schema under consideration **did** exist. Changing `search_path` (to try and finagle the desired schema from `current_schema`) won't help if the schema name being passed as `:v1` **doesn't exist** - that makes it more important that `:v1` gets passed to the `DO` so it can be used more directly.

Comment: Answering to "How can I pass the :v1 parameter to the DO script itself?" here is the trick: outside of the `DO` execute `prepare foo as select :'v1';` and then, inside the `DO` block `... execute 'execute foo' into this_schema;`. To remove prepared statement execute `deallocate foo;`

Comment: Yet another way: session variables. Outside of `DO`: `set foo.bar to :v1;` (dot in the name is required) and inside `DO` block `this_schema := current_setting('foo.bar');`

Comment: @Abelisto could you please make this an answer so it can be marked as the  answer? I didn't get the `prepare` version to work, but didn't spend much time on it: plus, the `set` version is more parsimonious, and can be included in the `DECLARE` block if a variable type declaration is added, i.e., `this_schema TEXT := current_setting('foo.bar');` . Thanks, GT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a temporary **function** instead of using a `DO` statement. That's the ***solution*** if you need to pass parameters.

```
CREATE FUNCTION pg_temp.f_create_schema(_schema text)  -- note function schema "pg_temp"
  RETURNS void AS 
$func$
DECLARE
   _date        text := to_char(current_date, 'YYYYMMDD');
   _save_schema text := _schema || _date;  -- unescaped identifier
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.schemata
              WHERE  schema_name = _save_schema) THEN  -- unescaped identifier
      EXECUTE format('DROP SCHEMA %I CASCADE', _save_schema);  -- escaped identifier!
   END IF;

   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.schemata
              WHERE  schema_name = _schema) THEN
      EXECUTE format(
        'ALTER SCHEMA %1$I RENAME TO %2$I;
         COMMENT ON SCHEMA %2$I IS $c$Schema renamed by SLSM creation on %3$s.$c$'
       , _schema, _save_schema, _date);
   END IF;

   EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA ' || quote_ident(_schema);
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT pg_temp.f_create_schema('Foo');  -- function name must be schema-qualified
```

From psql with [SQL interpolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION) using a variable `v1`:

```
SELECT pg_temp.f_create_schema(:'v1');
```

The schema name you pass for `_schema` is *case sensitive* and *unquoted*.

`pg_temp` is a pseudo name that translates to the temporary schema of the current session internally automatically. All objects in the temporary schema die at the ***end of the session***.

"Temporary" functions are not documented explicitly in the manual, but safe to use.

- [Is there such thing as a "temp function"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124912/is-there-such-thing-as-a-temp-function/29133390#29133390)

It makes sense if you need to the function once (or a few times) in the same session for varying databases. For repeated use in the same database, create a plain function instead.

Of course you need the [`TEMPORARY` privilege](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) for the database - which users have by default.

While being at it, I improved a couple of things:

- Escape identifiers to defend against **SQL injection** and ordinary syntax errors. Use [`quote_ident()` or `format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) for anything more complex.
- You don't need to concatenate a semicolon to the end of a single SQL command.
- You can `EXECUTE` multiple SQL statements at once. (Now you need a semicolon *between* statements.)
- Use [nested dollar quotes to avoid quoting hell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860).

There are all kinds of ***workarounds***, too:

- [Use variable set by psql meta-command inside of DO block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997527/use-variable-set-by-psql-meta-command-inside-of-do-block/28999217#28999217)
- [CREATE SEQUENCE using expressions with psql variables for parameters](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139681/create-sequence-using-expressions-with-psql-variables-for-parameters/139811#139811)

BTW, [customized options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-custom.html) ("session variables") require a two-part name (of the form *`extension.variable`*) for historic reasons. It proved to be useful in avoiding naming conflicts as much as possible.

Comment: I hadn't realised that it would be so much easier to pass command-line params to a `function` as opposed to a `DO`: given that the schema-creation stuff happens dozens of times a month it should be a function. Dollar quotes are something I really need to get a handle on, too.

Comment: @GT.: Note that the previous version had a sneaky bug that would only show for non-standard names: Queries to the system catalogs or the information schema must use *unescaped* strings. Also simplified some more.

Answer (score 7):

Because the PL blocks is actually text constants in the code the internal variables is not substituted inside them in the usual way. Fortunately it is possible to use a session variables for sharing data between different SQL/PL blocks:

```
set foo.bar to :v1; -- Name should contains the dot, don't ask me why 
show foo.bar; -- Check that the value was assigned 
do $$
declare
  myvar text := current_setting('foo.bar');
begin
  raise info '%', myvar; -- Output variable value
end $$;
```

To ensure that the variable is assigned and set the default value if it is not:

```
\if :{?v1}
  set foo.bar to :v1;
\else
  set foo.bar to 'default';
\endif
```

More details:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#PSQL-METACOMMAND-IF
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION

Comment: When the value "v1" is not passed in, the script errors out with "syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: SET att.cacheHostsInput to :cacheHostsInput;"
How do we make sure that the script run with some default value if the attribute is not passed in, i.e., optional parameters?

Comment: @sanchin Answer updated