# How to pass parameters to .sql file using psql command line?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.6

I have a bat file which have below command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.22\psql" -U postgres -h hostname -p 5432 -d TestDB -w -f 1.1.sql -v num_var=1.2
```

this command calls file 1.1.sql which have below script

```
DO $$
Begin 

If Exists (Select * from pg_statio_user_tables where relname = 'applicationsetting' ) then
update applicationsetting set value = :num_var
where applicationsettingid = '32bdba3b-39f6-4e43-947e-0bfdd4f5d561';
End IF;

End $$;
```

while clicking on bat file, I am getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CnGq.png)

```
psql:1.1.sql:9: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 4: update demo set keyvalue = :num_var
```

However, the code works fine if I don't pass any variable and use static value in the update query.

**EDIT**

Code also works fine if I use the update query only without DO block and if clause.

Comment: you get error on 9th line, please put first 10 lines of your 1.1. sql?..

Comment: @VaoTsun : updated question.

Answer (score 1):

No direct way, look into hacks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28999217/5315974) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38175213/5315974), eg:

prepare:

```
db=# create table t (c int);
CREATE TABLE
db=# insert into t values (0);
INSERT 0 1
```

your working update:

```
db=# \set num_var 1
db=# update t set c = :num_var;
UPDATE 1
db=# table t;
 c
---
 1
(1 row)
```

now hack for "nested quoting":

```
db=# \set num_var 2
db=# \set hack 'begin update t set c = ':num_var'; end';
db=# do :'hack';
DO
db=# table t;
 c
---
 2
(1 row)
```