# psql SQL Interpolation in a code block

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.6

In some of my scripts I use [SQL Interpolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION) feature of *psql* utility:

**basic.sql:**

```
update :schema.mytable set ok = true;

> psql -h 10.0.0.1 -U postgres -f basic.sql -v schema=myschema
```

Now I need bit more complicated scenario. I need to specify schema name (and desirebly some other things) inside PL/pgSQL code block:

**pg.sql**

```
do
$$
begin
  update :schema.mytable set ok = true;
end;
$$
```

But unfortunately this does not work, since *psql* does not replace `:variables` inside `$$`.

Is there a way to workaround it in general? Or more specifically, how to substitute schema names into pgSQL code block or function definition?

Comment: See [PSQL Command Line Arguments in DO script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38174506) and links within for some workarounds. But nothing as simple or straightforward as interpolation inside string done by psql, if it existed.

Comment: @DanielVérité, found something useful, but still no solution if two schemas need to be referenced (e.g. `source` and `dest`) apart form dynamic SQL, which I would like to avoid. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

in your referenced docs:

> Variable interpolation will not be performed within quoted SQL
>   literals and identifiers. Therefore, a construction such as ':foo'
>   doesn't work to produce a quoted literal from a variable's value (and
>   it would be unsafe if it did work, since it wouldn't correctly handle
>   quotes embedded in the value).

it does not matter if quotes are double dollar sign or single quote - it wont work, eg:

```
do
'
begin
  update :schema.mytable set ok = true;
end;
'
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
```

to pass variable into quoted statement other way you can try using shell variables, eg:

```
MacBook-Air:~ vao$ cat do.sh; export schema_name='smth' && bash do.sh
psql -X so <<EOF
\dn+
do
\$\$
begin
  execute format ('create schema %I','$schema_name');
end;
\$\$
;
\dn+
EOF

                         List of schemas
   Name   |  Owner   | Access privileges |      Description
----------+----------+-------------------+------------------------
 public   | vao      | vao=UC/vao       +| standard public schema
          |          | =UC/vao           |
 schema_a | user_old |                   |
(2 rows)

DO
                         List of schemas
   Name   |  Owner   | Access privileges |      Description
----------+----------+-------------------+------------------------
 public   | vao      | vao=UC/vao       +| standard public schema
          |          | =UC/vao           |
 schema_a | user_old |                   |
 smth     | vao      |                   |
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I see it clearly, but stil there is no answer how to deal with it.

Comment: Then it's better to use dynamic SQL, much more straightforward way for DB scripting.