# How to run plpgsql without creating a function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'd like to programmatically run a SQL in Postgres without creating a function.

Reason: to make sure my plpgsql works beforehand AND to "explain analyze" the query before committing it to a function.

I'm new to Postgres and I thought this would be simple. I couldn't find any example out there. Maybe it isn't possible? How can the code below work?

```
DO
$body$
DECLARE
  v_name_short VARCHAR;
BEGIN

v_name_short := 'test Account 1';

     RETURN QUERY
        SELECT 
            a.name_short, 
            a.name_long
        FROM enterprise.account a 
        WHERE 
            CASE WHEN v_name_short IS NOT NULL THEN
               LOWER(a.name_short) = LOWER(v_name_short)
            ELSE
               1 = 1   
            END;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Again, the goal here is TESTING my SQL, like in this case I want to make sure my CASE statement is still using an index I created (LOWER(name_short)). Anyhow, I get this error message:

> ERROR: cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function

Is what I'm asking possible in Postgres? If not, is there a way to query analyze plans inside a function?

Comment: Why do you use a `do` block to run an `explain`? why can't you simply run `explain select ...`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An anonymous code block returns void. However, you can use a trick with a temporary table, e.g.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trace (name_short text, name_long text);

DO
$body$
DECLARE
    v_name_short VARCHAR;
BEGIN

    v_name_short := 'test Account 1';

    INSERT INTO trace 
        SELECT 
            a.name_short, 
            a.name_long
        FROM enterprise.account a 
        WHERE 
            CASE WHEN v_name_short IS NOT NULL THEN
               LOWER(a.name_short) = LOWER(v_name_short)
            ELSE
               1 = 1   
            END;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'; 

SELECT * FROM trace;
-- DROP TABLE trace;
```

---

With `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` you can analyse only a single plain sql query, not a function, a do block nor a script. So you can try:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
    SELECT 
        a.name_short, 
        a.name_long
    FROM enterprise.account a 
    WHERE 
        CASE WHEN 'test Account 1' IS NOT NULL THEN
           LOWER(a.name_short) = LOWER('test Account 1')
        ELSE
           1 = 1   
        END;
```

Note that in this case you cannot use the variable beacuse it won't be recognized by the planner, use the literal instead.

Comment: Klin, thanks for your answer. I'm just surprised I can't run this cleanly in Postgres. Although your solution executes, I can't run an "explain analyze" from pgAdmin, as it bombs right in the CREATE statement (which can't be analyzed). I guess I need to figure out a way to analyze a query plan inside a function...

Comment: You can analyse only a single plain sql query, not a function, a do block nor a script. In the case try `explain analyse select ...` but you cannot use the variable. Put the literal `'test Account 1'` instead.

Comment: Klin, a favor: would you mind updating your answer with the comment you just posted? Then the answer will be completed and I can mark it as accepted. Thanks so much again for your help!

Answer (score 8):

A [`do`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) anonymous code block always returns `void`:

> The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, returning void

To execute queries inside a `do` block use `perform`

```
do $$
    begin
    perform * from t;
    end
$$;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to execute the code above with an alternate syntax?

Comment: We're one step closer, but now I get this: "Query returned successfully with no result in 28 msec". Now, there is a result... but like you said "DO" always returns void. Is there a way to run the query without DO then? Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 5):

There is a third option between a regular PL/pgSQL function and a `DO` statement: a **temporary function**. It's not documented explicitly, but it's just using standard Postgres features.

- [How to create a temporary function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990622/how-to-create-temporary-function-in-postgres/31095452#31095452)
- [Is there such thing as a "temp function"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124912/is-there-such-thing-as-a-temp-function/29133390#29133390)

And you actually **can** get detailed query plans for SQL statements nested in PL/pgSQL code blocks with the additional module [**auto-explain**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html). See:

- [Get query plan for SQL statement nested in a PL/pgSQL function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23357/3684)

But you'll have to test your function with values for each branch in your `CASE` expression to make sure to cover everything. Postgres only does superficial syntax checks on `CREATE FUNCTION`.

[Prepared statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) may be another option to work with. PL/pgSQL handles SQL statements much like prepared statements internally:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)