# Postgres calling a void function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

I have a void plsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_something(p_id BIGINT) 
RETURNS void
AS $$
BEGIN
   insert ....
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

I want to call this function from another plsql function, but inside a query like:

```
SELECT  do_something(m.id) 
FROM    MyTable m
WHERE   m.IsActive;
```

When I run the `sproc` i get:

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data HINT:  If you want to
>   discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.

Is it possible to call a void function as part of a `select` statement?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> HINT: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.

```
PERFORM  do_something(m.id) 
FROM    MyTable m
WHERE   m.IsActive;
```

`PERFORM` is the PL/PgSQL alternative for `SELECT` for when you want to throw the results away. It cannot be used outside PL/PgSQL. For more information, see the manual.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning, `PERFORM` is only valid in pl/pgsql context.

Comment: Yeah, fair. I usually write much more in depth answers, but this is such a "Did you actually read the error message / search for the error" one...

Comment: :-) I Did read the error and I did try "PERFORM"...but I must have fluffed it up...because before it didnt work...and now it does...grrr ...and sorry for wasting everyones time.