# How to create procedure in pgadmin-4?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, pgadmin-4

I firsted looked and followed tutorials for creating procedures in SQL. But when I tried to apply the syntax to pgadmin-4 it didn't work. I googled around and found out that in pgadmin-4 you can only create procedures in the "create procedure dialog". But I cant locate it.
where do i find the "create procedure dialog" in Pg4? Or am I totally missinformed about the way to create procedures?

Thanks for any replies!

Comment: You simply run `create procedure ....` or `create function ...` wherever you run SQL statements in pgAdmin.

Comment: But thats what i started with, I kept getting syntax error....... could please provide an example query of how that query ought to look like? I tried this:

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE dwd.spGet_Org
as
begin
 select counterparty_id, organisation_name
 from dwd_cpty_organizations
end

Comment: when writing that query im getting a red underscore under "procedure" and this error message :ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PROCEDURE"
LINE 1: CREATE PROCEDURE dwd.spGet_Org
               ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 8

Comment: You cannot expect us to provide a tutorial on writing PostgreSQL functions... but [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) should help you.

Comment: Support for stored procedures was added in Postgres 11. Which version are you using? `select version();` will tell you.

Comment: For one, you need parentheses, even if there are no arguments.

Comment: thats fair enough!

Comment: i looked at a tutorial on youtube and simply followed his syntax. It worked for him, but he was on MySQL. So it seems as it differs between the two.
Thanks for the guidance ill take it from here.

Comment: "PostgreSQL 9.6.15 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit"

Comment: ah in this version only create function exists. Thanks for the input a horse with no name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Procedures are only available as of PostgreSQL 11.

Comment: So what do you suggest i use instead?

Comment: Try to create a function that returns void:  example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216716/how-to-create-function-that-returns-nothing.